# Invoking a ajax post upon user clickin a link or button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="id_1">
                        <a href="/Path" >Name</a>   <a href="#">Delete</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="id_2">
                        <a href="/Path" >Name</a>   <a href="#" >Delete</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Hi there!

I have a table as above, I am interested in firing an ajax post upon delete clicked.

I am unsure how i can determine which Delete was clicked. I have the luxury of adding whatever id i want.

Then on the jquery side :

```
    $.post("/Attachment/RemoveAttachment", { id: "1", fooId: , barId: })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

I need to ensure this is fired only upon the user clicks on a Delete button.

Any help is appreaciated

Comment: Where is your `click` handler?

Comment: that s where I am not sure, how i should do it? there will be a list of a links. and how do i come up with a single one?

Comment: I guess you got a few good answers already, have a look if any of them help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each delete link a class of 'delete':

```
<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

Then write an event handler for the onclick event which will fire your AJAX call:

```
$('a.delete').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('id_', '');
    // your AJAX call goes here
    // var id contains the id from the span, so place it where appropriate
    $.post('/Attachment/RemoveAttachment', {
        id: '1',
        fooId: ,
        barId: 
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: well how do i get the id or the value of the other link?

Comment: @DarthVader, is the id in the span?  If so, I've edited my answer to extract the id from the span.

Comment: yeah i can do that. no problemo

Comment: this `var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('id_', '');` didnt work homes.

Comment: i still get id_1 as the id. when i put an alert there.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that.  As you can see from http://jsfiddle.net/GzDeF/, my code works.

Answer (score 2):

In response to, "I am unsure how i can determine which Delete was clicked."  Please see the following:

**HTML:**

```
<td>
                    <span id="id_2">
                        <a href="/Path" >Name</a>   <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.post("/Attachment/RemoveAttachment", { id: id, fooId: , barId: })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an attribute which holds the id (cleaner IMHO). In the handler you read it:

```
<a href="#" data-id="2" class="delete">Delete</a>

$('a.delete').click(function () {
var theId = $(this).attr("data-id");
// delete ...
$.post("/Attachment/RemoveAttachment", { id: theId })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
});
```

Comment: @DartVader: I was not as fast as Warappa. Since i already made [a similar demo plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eccAKyWuamBGljiKflfQ?p=preview) i link to it as a comment.

Comment: i actually like that fact that u used data-id